# MailCore: Offline HTML Rendering

Tags: ios, objective-c, mailcore2

It doesn't seem possible to use `htmlBodyRenderingOperationWithMessage:` when offline (I get the error A stable connection to the server could not be established.). Why is this?

I already have the MCOIMAPMessage stored locally and thought it contained everything necessary to render the message. Is `htmlBodyRenderingOperationWithMessage:` pulling more data from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods for rendering of `MCOIMAPSession` have limited capabilities.

To support offline rendering of message, you should use:

`-[MCOIMAPMessage htmlRenderingWithFolder:delegate:]`

Use `MCOHTMLRendererIMAPDelegate` to provide offline data required to render the message.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Would I use this as a replacement for ```htmlBodyRenderingOperationWithMessage:``` or only when I need to render offline?