# Mailcore2 Viewing Email content is empty in Offline

Tags: ios, objective-c, mailcore2

I am able to store MCOIMAPMessage in persistent storage to use when device is not having internet. I am able to display the listing of emails table view. Now, When I open any email, it should open with the relevant content even when the device is in offline. But, it is not showing the email content when the iPhone is not having internet connection.

I am setting the required properties properly in here, even when the device is offline,
Masterviewcontroller.m:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

switch (indexPath.section)
{
    case 0:
    {
        MCOIMAPMessage *msg = self.messages[indexPath.row];
        //selectedMessage = self.messages[indexPath.row];

        // Setting email flag as READ status
        MCOIMAPOperation *op = [self.imapSession storeFlagsOperationWithFolder:folderList.selectedFolder
                                                                 uids:[MCOIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:msg.uid]
                                                                 kind:MCOIMAPStoreFlagsRequestKindAdd
                                                                flags:MCOMessageFlagSeen];
        [op start:^(NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Updated flags");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Error updating flags: %@", error);
            }
        }];

        MCTMsgViewController *vc = [[MCTMsgViewController alloc] init];
        //vc.folder = @"INBOX";
        vc.folder = folderList.selectedFolder;
        vc.message = msg;
        vc.session = self.imapSession;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

        break;
    }
```

and in MCOMessageView.mm, it has been using "htmlRenderingWithFolder"

```
    - (void) _refresh
{
    NSString * content;

    if (_message == nil) {
        content = nil;
    }
    else {
        if ([_message isKindOfClass:[MCOIMAPMessage class]]) {
            content = [(MCOIMAPMessage *) _message htmlRenderingWithFolder:_folder delegate:self];

            AppDelegate *appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
            appDelegate.mailBodyMessage = content;
        }
        else if ([_message isKindOfClass:[MCOMessageBuilder class]]) {
            content = [(MCOMessageBuilder *) _message htmlRenderingWithDelegate:self];
        }
        else if ([_message isKindOfClass:[MCOMessageParser class]]) {
            content = [(MCOMessageParser *) _message htmlRenderingWithDelegate:self];
        }
        else {
            content = nil;
            MCAssert(0);
        }
    }
    if (content == nil) {
        [_webView loadHTMLString:@"" baseURL:nil];
        return;
    }

    NSMutableString * html = [NSMutableString string];
    [html appendFormat:@"<html><head><script>%@</script><style>%@</style></head>"
        @"<body>%@</body><iframe src='x-mailcore-msgviewloaded:' style='width: 0px; height: 0px; border: none;'>"
        @"</iframe></html>", mainJavascript, mainStyle, content];
    [_webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}
```

But, Content of any email shows empty here when opening an email from Masterviewcontroller.m.

Please correct me what I have to do properly here for displaying Email content even when the device is in offline mode.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342382/mailcore-offline-html-rendering

Comment: This is not working -[MCOIMAPMessage htmlRenderingWithFolder:delegate:] , that is the reason why I created this question. I mentioned all the code. Please help to solve this.

Comment: Finally I fixed this viewing mails in offline state.

Comment: Great, could you post your solution for others with the same problem in the future?